# Escaping square bracket in JSel

Tags: javascript, json, xpath

I am using [JSel](https://github.com/dragonworx/jsel) to query content that is parsed JSON and I have some entries with brackets such as:

```
"R.GenericPmRelationship[ProjectImpactsCapability]"
```

and other with just a dot and those work fine.

I have tried to use a backslash but that is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
//@*[contains(name(),"R.GenericPmRelationship[ProjectImpactsCapability]")]
```

Tested OK here : http://dragonworx.github.io/jsel/